# keeping a division visible in the screen

Tags: javascript

I am creating a web page in which when user hovers on an image it displays a paragraph which is enclosed in a division under it. When the user moves the cursur out of the image the division disappears.

My problem is that when the user clicks the image which is in the bottom of the screen.. i want the page to be scrolled using **javascript** until the division at the bottom is visible...

I want to know how to do this one. Which function to use??

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: let the code speak for itself. where's your code? what have you tried?

Comment: i tried to use the `window.scrollBy(x,y)` function... but actully i am not getting how to find out the position of a `div` with respect to screen?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will need to calculate height of your browser window.... then also know the height of your image and it's offset (i.e. where it is placed)...

doing some maths you will get the additional page scroll you want to have...
simply do it...

Here are some functions for you:

```
in Internet Explorer (backward-compatibility mode):
document.body.offsetWidth, document.body.offsetHeight

in Internet Explorer (standards mode, document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat'):
document.documentElement.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.offsetHeight

in most other browsers – as well as IE9 (standards mode):
window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight (the page's visible width/height)
window.outerWidth, window.outerHeight (the browser outer width/height)
```

take directly from here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm
you can check more specific examples here on how to calculate required parameters.